# CocoaPod pod installed but not working

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have installed the SideMenu pod for Swift.

I have run all the commands in the terminal and it says the pod has installed and there is one dependency. My podfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ’10.3’

use_frameworks!

target ‘AppName’ do 
project ‘/Users/name/Documents/3/iOS/App/AppName’

pod 'SideMenu'
end
```

However, when I open Xcode the pod doesn't work. I have a 'Pod' file added to my project but a lot of the stuff, including the framework, appear red as though they are missing. I try to import SideMenu in to a swift file and it says that no such module exists. Is there something I am mssing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you open the .xcworkspace file?

Comment: No workspace file has been created. I did research and understood that workspace files are not created with Swift and it relies on frameworks - hence the 'use frameworks'. That's what the terminal told me as well when I tried to force a workspace file to be created by removing that line.